# Deploying application to open source server

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using weblogic server for deploying adf application and I want to know whether is there any open source server available with security  for adf application deployment?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only wls allows you to use the default adf security.
You can deploy adf essentials to other servers like tomcat but you can't you adf security then.